# A macro to automatically show the steps to solve equations with conditions for positive or negative addends

Tags: best-practices, pgfkeys

I would like to design a macro so that I can solve an algebra equation such as 2(x-3)=14 and show the steps. Here is what I have that seems to work but I am pretty sure its not best practice.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{examdesign}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\SectionFont{\large\sffamily}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}  %%shortlabels here for matchign
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} %%%%%%%%%%%for marking angles
%\usetkzobj{all}  %%%%%%%%%%%for marking angles
% \usepackage{tikz} % euclide loads tikz
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,matrix}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering
\ShortKey
%%\NoKey
\DefineAnswerWrapper{}{}
\NumberOfVersions{1}
\IncludeFromFile{foobar.tex}
%%%%%Title of the Assignment
\class{{needed for examdesign}}

\usepackage{docmute}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\begin{shortanswer}[title={Solving Equations involving the Distributive Property},rearrange=no,resetcounter=no]

\begin{question}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Question 2
Solve the following equations using the distributive property.
\begin{enumerate} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\newcommand\coeff{2}
\newcommand\addend{4}
\newcommand\exaddend{\the\numexpr\addend*\coeff\relax}
\newcommand\result{14}
\newcommand\resultrest{\the\numexpr(\result-\exaddend)\relax}
            \item \begin{align*}
            \coeff(x+\addend)&=\result\\
        \coeff x+\exaddend&=\result \\
        -\exaddend&=-\exaddend\\
        \coeff x&=\resultrest\\
        \frac{\cancel{\coeff}x}{\cancel{\coeff}}&=\frac{\resultrest}{\coeff}\\
        x&=\boxed{\the\numexpr\resultrest/\coeff\relax}
        \end{align*} \vspace{1em} 
    \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\newcommand\coeff{2}
\newcommand\subtrahend{3}
\newcommand\exsubtrahend{\the\numexpr\subtrahend*\coeff}
\newcommand\result{14}
\newcommand\resultrest{\the\numexpr(\result+\exsubtrahend)\relax}
            \item \begin{align*}
            \coeff(x-\subtrahend)&=\result\\
        \coeff x-\exsubtrahend&=\result \\
        +\exsubtrahend&=+\exsubtrahend\\
        \coeff x&=\resultrest\\
        \frac{\cancel{\coeff}x}{\cancel{\coeff}}&=\frac{\resultrest}{\coeff}\\
        x&=\boxed{\the\numexpr\resultrest/\coeff\relax}
        \end{align*} \vspace{1em} 
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
\end{enumerate}
\begin{answer}
\end{answer}
\end{question}
\end{shortanswer}
\end{document}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a macro that can automate this process of showing all these steps.  One of the difficulties I'm running into is I have to make new commands for addends(positive) and subtrahends(when I'm adding a negative)  Is there a way perhaps with a conditional loop like `\ifnum`  if the number is positive, subtract, and if its negative add to both sides.  .
I guess I'm also looking for best practice in case you notice bad ways that I'm doing this.
In short, 
Can you give me direction on writing a macro to solve the equations and show the steps taking into account the condition of the extra constant being positive or negative.
Other equations I"m also looking at simplifying include x/a+b=c and 2x+4=10 so I will try to understand the code so I can adapt them to new situations.  Thanks in advance.

Here is the output of the code above:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I do not have `tkz-obj-angles.tex` installed, so could you please post a screenshot of what your code produces? Am I right in thinking that you just want to automatically solve, with explanations, equations of the form `a(x-b)=c`? This is certainly possible but is it worth the effort?

Comment: The tkzobj is a old installation of tikz but I"m using Overleaf so I don't think you need it.  I guess the current code works but I would rather not copy paste and check to see if I made a negative addend by mistake so if someone can help me with the macro, yes, it would help.  It's also an opportunity to learn in the midst of what I'm doing instead of trying to study things I don't really know that I need yet.

Comment: You're right, the `\usetkzobj{all}` is not needed so I have removed it (for a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) you should remove all unnecessary code), and added an image. Personally, I would divide by 2 first:)  If no one else answers then I will look at this when I have a little more time.

Comment: It seems that this is not most effective step by step solution. What about this: 2(x+4)=14, x+4=14/2=7, x=7-4=3.

Comment: @wipet You are right.  Your method here is the most effective but usually I'm showing these solutions to middle school students who would probably want to avoid fractions as long as possible.  In my method, the last step is the only fraction they encounter(as long as the parameters are integers).  but of course, at a certain point they will have to  be exposed to either method.